# carrying HDDs on international flight as a carry-on?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security, sfo, bom

I purchased 2 x 4TB WD Reds in USA and I want to carry them with me back to my home country i.e. India.

My flight is direct flight from SFO to BOM. Its Indian airline. I chose this flight to try out their direct flights instead of layover.

Anyways, I want to carry 2 x 4TB 3.5" internal hard disks with me. These are new hard disks, I have opened them and put them back in the antistatic bag they came in and have taped them. I am planning on carrying both in carry-on for obvious reasons. Will I be allowed to carry them without any issues with customs? I also have my laptop with me.

I have an option to carry only one and ask a relative who will be flying back in the next 10 days to carry the other HDD.

I would prefer it if both were with me but if I will be stopped at customs then I would rather opt for carrying only one and sending the other with my folks.

Any suggestions / recommendations how I should carry these disks back with me?

Comment: Is it customs or security? Which one. Security makes sure you don't blow up the plane. Customs makes sure you pay your taxes.

Comment: I guess then it would be customs. To avoid taxes

Answer (score 4):

That's not an issue for security. Customs depends on the value of the drive. As an Indian citizen, I believe you have a customs allowance of Rs50,000 which should be fine (unless these are really expensive drives).

It would be good to bring the receipts.

https://www.immihelp.com/duty-free-baggage-allowance-rules-for-indian-residents-and-persons-of-indian-origin/

Comment: The cost of both the drives is around $110 including taxes. So like you mentioned definitely below Rs.50,000/-